# Why am I getting "302 Moved" from the C2DM servers?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In using Android Cloud to Device Messaging my app successfully acquires a registration ID from ClientLogin, and successfully registers to receive push notifications. But when I attempt to send a push notification to the C2DM servers to be sent to a device, I get a "302 Moved". The URL I'm posting to is https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send

I have had an email (48hrs ago) from Google saying the account:
"has been added to our list of allowed senders, and you should be able to start using it to send messages to Android 2.2 devices within the next
day or so"

That was two days ago, so I assume it's up and running. Does the 302 mean the account hasn't been set up, that the URL has moved, or something else?

Google really don't make these things easy do they.

Comment: What is the value of the Location: header in the server response?

Comment: Location: http://www.google.com

I have seen comments suggesting that when an account isn't active, it can return 302, but the email suggested it would be active in a day or so, and it's been two days. But perhaps I just need to wait.

Comment: Google have confirmed that the C2DM account HAS been white-listed, so I'm left completely baffled. I wish the server responded with an error message that meant something. Right now I'm completely stuck for what to try next. I've posted to the C2DM google group, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug in the way I was acquiring the auth code from ClientLogin. I was not correctly parsing the response from ClientLogin.

For anyone else facing this error - it can occur if your C2DM authentication is not working, so check your auth code.